# uncaught reference error while using setter method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let person = {
  _name: 'Lu Xun',
  _age: 137,

  set age(ageIn) {
    if (typeof ageIn === 'number') {
      this._age = ageIn;
    }
    else {
      console.log('Invalid input');
      return 'Invalid input';
    }
  }

};
console.log(person.set age('bdhh'));
```

//  While executing the code is is giving error as uncaught reference 
   error

Comment: When I run that I get `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and not the error you say it gives. Try providing a real [mcve] (and quote the **full** error message)\

Comment: The age is a setter, hence *person.age='bdhh';*

Comment: `person.set age('bdhh')` that's not how setters are used - a quick trip to documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Examples

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the setter the wrong way.

```
person.age = 15; // this is how you call your setter
```

See your updated code in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3uzpobn/4/

Answer (score 0):

The way you call the setter is not correct:

```js
let person = {
  _name: 'Lu Xun',
  _age: 137,

  set age(ageIn) {
    if (typeof ageIn === 'number') {
      this._age = ageIn;
    }
    else {
      console.log('Invalid input');
      return 'Invalid input';
    }
  }

};
console.log(person.age = 'bdhh');
console.log(person.age = 13);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calling method is not correct

```
let person = {
  _name: 'Lu Xun',
  _age: 137,

  set age(ageIn) {
    if (typeof ageIn === 'number') {
      this._age = ageIn;
    }
    else {
      console.log('Invalid input');
      return 'Invalid input';
    }
  }

};
console.log(person.age = 'bdhh');
```